# ChartJS tooltip scrollbar to prevent data overflow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am working with a chartJS where I have callback function to display data in tooltip. As data increase overflow section of Tooltip is hidden from canvas. Is there a way to prevent overflow of tooltip and add a scrollbar to scroll the data in tooltip?

below is the section of tooltip config

```
  options: {
        responsive: true,

        tooltips: {
          yAlign: "bottom",
          enabled: true,
          callbacks: {
            label: function () {
              const item = ["Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1"]
              let finalLabelValue = [];
              item.map(single => finalLabelValue.push(single))
              return finalLabelValue;
            }
          },
        },
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to add scrollbar in tooltip and prevent overflow from canvas?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. If you really need such big tooltips you should switch to an external [HTML tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips).

```js
const getOrCreateTooltip = (chart) => {
  let tooltipEl = chart.canvas.parentNode.querySelector('div');

  if (!tooltipEl) {
    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipEl.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)';
    tooltipEl.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    tooltipEl.style.color = 'white';
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
    tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
    tooltipEl.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, 0)';
    tooltipEl.style.transition = 'all .1s ease';

    const table = document.createElement('table');
    table.style.margin = '0px';

    tooltipEl.appendChild(table);
    chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
  }

  return tooltipEl;
};

const externalTooltipHandler = (context) => {
  // Tooltip Element
  const {chart, tooltip} = context;
  const tooltipEl = getOrCreateTooltip(chart);

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    const titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    const bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(b => b.lines);

    const tableHead = document.createElement('thead');

    titleLines.forEach(title => {
      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const th = document.createElement('th');
      th.style.borderWidth = 0;
      const text = document.createTextNode(title);

      th.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tableHead.appendChild(tr);
    });

    const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    bodyLines.forEach((body, i) => {
      const colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];

      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.style.background = colors.backgroundColor;
      span.style.borderColor = colors.borderColor;
      span.style.borderWidth = '2px';
      span.style.marginRight = '10px';
      span.style.height = '10px';
      span.style.width = '10px';
      span.style.display = 'inline-block';

      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
      tr.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const text = document.createTextNode(body);

      td.appendChild(span);
      td.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });

    const tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');

    // Remove old children
    while (tableRoot.firstChild) {
      tableRoot.firstChild.remove();
    }

    // Add new children
    tableRoot.appendChild(tableHead);
    tableRoot.appendChild(tableBody);
  }

  const {offsetLeft: positionX, offsetTop: positionY} = chart.canvas;

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.font = tooltip.options.bodyFont.string;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.options.padding + 'px ' + tooltip.options.padding + 'px';
};

const myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
                enabled: false,

                external: externalTooltipHandler
             }
        }
    }
});
```